# mutiple pthreads (workers) do different functions

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to understand and implement a multiple threads program where each thread will do a different function and share the values in  global parameters

Mmy code is supposed to take numbers from the user put them in an array and then pass the array to 3 threads

- 1st one does the minimum.
- 2nd one does the maximum.
- 3rd one does the average.

.initializing and array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//global parameters 
int max;
int min;
float avrg;
int size;


void *runmin(void *varg) //min function
{
    size_t i;
    int *arr = (int *) varg;
    min = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (min > arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }

}

void *runmax(void *varg) //max function
{
    size_t i;
    int *arr = (int *) varg;
    max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (max < arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }        
}

void *runavrg(void *varg) //avrg function
{
    int *arr = (int *) varg;

    int sum = 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i){
        sum+=arr[i];    
    }

    printf("this is the size %d" ,sum);
    avrg =sum/size;
}

 //gcc main.c -lpthread
 //./a.out

int main()
{   //************** initializing an array************
    int num;
    printf("Enter the numbers you want to be processed?\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int list[size];

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("Enter number\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &num);
        list[i]= num;
    }

    //creating threads
    pthread_t tid,tid1,tid2;
    printf("Before Threads\n");
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, runmin, (void*) &list); 
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, runmax, (void*) &list);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, runavrg, (void*) &list);
    //waiting for the threads to finish
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    //print the global values
    printf("\n  After Thread the min is %d \n ", min);
    printf("\n  After Thread the max is %d \n ", max);
    printf("\n  After Thread the avrg is %.2f \n ", avrg);
}
```

My code works but I want to know if my logic is correct especially in the creating threads part, and what could be a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

Few points,

1. You can avoid global variables by enclosing them in some data structure and pass pointer to that data structure to each and every thread.
2. Better to dynamically allocate the memory for the list instead of doing it at runtime, following is bad practice,

   scanf("%d", &size);
   int list[size];